# Add dates from monthcalendar with loop to mdb

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb

I'm currently trying to add multiple Dates into an Access MdB by using a monthcalendar.

The idea is that for every selected Date would be an entry inserted into the database.

This is the Code i use to get the range from my monthcalendar:

```
public void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {

        string start = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
        string end = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End.ToShortDateString();

        DateTime startDay = Convert.ToDateTime(start); 
        DateTime endDay = Convert.ToDateTime(end); 

        while (startDay < endDay)
        {

            DateTime Day = startDay.AddDays(1);
            string Day1 = Day.ToShortDateString();}}
```

This Code should be executed for every selected date when pressing the button:

```
public void btn_speichern_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
          {
                 if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
         {
                //con.Open();

                string Vacation = "Vacation";
                command.Connection = con;
                command.CommandText = "insert into " + user + " (Date, Worktime) values ('" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "', '" + Vacation + "')";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                string query = "select * from " + user;
                command.CommandText = query;

                OleDbDataAdapter Daten = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable Datenquelle = new DataTable();

                Daten.Fill(Datenquelle);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = Datenquelle;

                dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = true;
                dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = true;
                dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

                int totalRowHeight = dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight;

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                    totalRowHeight += row.Height;

                dataGridView1.Height = totalRowHeight;
                this.Height = dataGridView1.Height + 100;

                con.Close();
            }
            }
```

But i'm at a loss at how i can execute the Code for every date selected until it reaches the end date....pretty sure i have to Change the datetimepicker1.text but im not sure how.

I'd be really grateful for every helpful answer. 
Thanks in advance everyone. :)

Comment: When you are dealing with Access DB, always use parametrized queries, always!! When you deal with dates, just parsing values will get you into loads of trouble and the chance of format errors and data types missmatches will give a headache...

Answer (score 0):

You've got it pretty close. Just add a couple of `DateTime` variables on the form to store `startDay` and `endDay`.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private DateTime _startDate {get; set;}
    private DateTime _endDate {get; set;}

    // your other code
}
```

And assign them when then user selects a date range:

public void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{

```
string start = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
string end = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End.ToShortDateString();

DateTime startDay = Convert.ToDateTime(start); 
DateTime endDay = Convert.ToDateTime(end); 

_StartDate = startDay;
_endDate = endDay;

while (startDay < endDay)
{
    DateTime Day = startDay.AddDays(1);
    string Day1 = Day.ToShortDateString();
}
```

}

And then you can access them in your button's click method:

```
public void btn_speichern_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    do 
    {
        //probably want a do..while here, so if they select a single day it still goes once.
        //now do your other stuff, and then increment _startDate

        _startDate = _startDate.AddDays(1);
    }
    while (_startDate <= _endDate)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer!

Unfortunately if i implement it my Programm freezes when i select more than one date....? 

I implemented your "do while" Code just after my "if (checkBox2.Checked == true)" .....could that be why?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a parametrized query for the dates (and for everything else). Will save you a lot of trouble. You could write yourself a methot, which takes the values in a dictionary and then loads the command parameters. Here is a bried example for the date.

```
  //_date is your date value and conS is your connection string
    public int InsertDate(DateTime _date, string conS) 
    {
          try
          {
                using (var cn = new OleDbConnection(conS))
                {
                      string queryString = "INSERT INTO... some_date_field=@dateparam"; //your query
                      var cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryString, cn);              
                      cmd.Parameters
                      .Add(new OleDbParameter("@dateparam", _date)); // add the parameter
                      cn.Open();
                      int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                      return res;
                 }
         }
         catch
         {
               return -2; // if you get that you will know something has gone wrong
         }
    }
```

This is just a demo for the date field insertion.